# Moving multiple .jpgs from one directory to a subdirectory within a subdirectory

Tags: python, directory, move, subdirectory

```
import os
import shutil
import glob
i = 0

    Source = "L:\\source\\GIS\\Natural_Resource\\Trees\\TreeWatch\\2019\\TreePhotos"
    destination = "L:\\source\\Natural Resources\\Tree_Folders\\MULTIPLE_TREE_NAMES\\Photos"

destination_list = os.listdir(Source)
data_dir_list = os.listdir(destination)
for fileName in destination_list:
   if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Source, fileName)):
       for prefix in data_dir_list:
           if fileName.startswith(prefix):
               shutil.move(os.path.join(Source, fileName),
                           os.path.join(destination, prefix, fileName))
               print (fileName + " copied")`
               i=i+1`
               print ("Total Photos Copied:", i)
```

I am trying to take a folder full of photos taken over a year, separate them out to the correct folder based on a number the photo is labeled as, corresponding the the "tree's" number and then once it has moved into the corresponding numbered folder within that folder i have a photo folder that the photos for that specific "tree" will need to be placed in. The code above moves it to the corresponding numbered folder, but I don't know how to get it into the photos folder then to be able to loop back out of it and continue with the other ~600 photos

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Can you elaborate please? What do you want to 'loop out of'? (btw, there's a rogue ` on the 2nd last line)

Comment: the code I posted is halfway good. It moves the photos from the staging folder to the appropriate "tree folder" but I need to make it where it will move the photos from the staging folder to the folder labeled photos within the appropriate "tree" folder. Does that make sense?

Comment: Could you send an example file name? If I understand right, you want to move `2020-01-01-Beech-Tree-12345.jpg` into `2020/01/01/Beech-Tree/12345.jpg`?

Comment: photos taken in field will be labeled tree number, ex. 6540. so then 6540.jpg will need to move into the folder 6540. Which the code above does. Inside folder 6540 there are 10 folders to separate different types of paperwork and photos. So the code i need help with is; instead of it just putting the 6540.jpg in folder 6540, i need it to go into the photo folder inside the 6540 folder. Should look something like this when then photos are in the correct location: (treephotos\6540.jpg -> treeFolder\6540\photos\6540.jpg)

Comment: you still didn't send the full file name of the jpg, if i understood

Comment: full file name for source would be:  L:\NaturalResource\treephotos\6540.jpg (would hold 500-1000 photos) Full file name for destination would be : L:\NaturalResource\treeFolder\6540\photos\6540.jpg (treeFolder would have ~2000 or so different tree folder ranging 6201-8280)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace the `shutil.move` line with:

```py
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(destination, prefix, "photos"), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.move(os.path.join(Source, fileName),
                os.path.join(destination, prefix, "photos", fileName))
```

And it ought to work. This basically creates a new folder called "photos" if it doesn't already exist, and moves the file there instead. I hope that's what you wanted

Comment: That was it! You're amazing, I don't care what anybody else says about you. Thank you for all your help and the time you invested into answering my question.

Comment: @jtace you can accept the answer by clicking the green tick (and the up arrow to upvote)